# How can I make an iframe exand outside of its container

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

We have a site that was programed using adobe muse by a third party, and it is using an iframe to display a section of the site.  However this iframe is stuck in a container that is preventing the frame from reaching all the way across the screen from left to right.  I would like to make this frame dynamically fill the entire screen horizontaly.

The code generated by MUSE for the frame is:

```
<iframe class="actAsDiv" src="https://mypage.com/page.php" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="My Page" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="1000px" width="1160px"></iframe>
```

Making the width dynamic and setting the frame to 100% width actually shrinks the frame down to 1/4 of the screen.  I think what I need to do is offset the frame, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it all the way to the left and then dynamically set the width based on how wide the window is.

I am trying to use jquery to set the width of the iframe when the window size is changed, but it doesn't seem to be changing.

```
<script>
        $(window).resize(function(){
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();
            $("#actAsDiv").css("width", windowWidth);
         });
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you remove unneeded attributes from the `iframe`?

Comment: We have no idea what the container structure or css is. Solution would be dependent on that. Provide a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: I wondered if you have overflow: hidden on the parent element.

Answer (score -1):

Change your selector $("#actAsDiv"), you're not using an id on your iframe so change it to $(".actAsDiv")